# html/css interactive calendar next/prev day button coding

Tags: javascript, html, css, calendar, interactive

I am using a tutorial I found online to fit my needs for a project.  I would like to add in functional buttons that select between days (changing "active" days in calendar) and select between months.

My first question is how do I code the prev day and next day buttons to change the previous and next day to active according to css?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <style>
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    ul {
      list-style-type: none;
    }
    body {
      font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    }
    .month {
      padding: 70px 25px;
      width: 100%;
      background: #1abc9c;
    }
    .month ul {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    .month ul li {
      color: white;
      font-size: 40px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      letter-spacing: 3px;
    }
    .month .prev {
      float: left;
      padding-top: 10px;
    }
    .month .prevDay {
      float: left;
    }
    .month .next {
      float: right;
      padding-top: 10px;
    }
    .month .nextDay {
      float: right;
    }
    .weekdays {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 10px 0;
      background-color: #ddd;
    }
    .weekdays li {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 13.6%;
      color: #666;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .days {
      padding: 10px 0;
      background: #eee;
      margin: 0;
    }
    .days li {
      list-style-type: none;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 13.6%;
      text-align: center;
      margin-bottom: 5px;
      font-size: 12px;
      color: #777;
    }
    .days li .active {
      padding: 5px;
      background: #1abc9c;
      color: white !important
    }
    /* Add media queries for smaller screens */
    @media screen and (max-width: 720px) {
      .weekdays li,
      .days li {
        width: 13.1%;
      }
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 420px) {
      .weekdays li,
      .days li {
        width: 12.5%;
      }
      .days li .active {
        padding: 2px;
      }
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 290px) {
      .weekdays li,
      .days li {
        width: 12.2%;
      }
    }
  </style>

  <style>
    .pM_button {
      padding: 15px 25px;
      font-size: 24px;
      text-align: center;
      cursor: pointer;
      outline: none;
      color: #cc9900;
      background-color: #ffff00;
      border: none;
      border-radius: 15px;
      box-shadow: 0 9px #999;
    }
    .pM_button:hover {
      background-color: #ffff00
    }
    .pM_button:active {
      background-color: #ffcc00;
      box-shadow: 0 5px #666;
      transform: translateY(4px);
    }
    .nM_button {
      padding: 15px 25px;
      font-size: 24px;
      text-align: center;
      cursor: pointer;
      outline: none;
      color: #ffffff;
      background-color: #9900cc;
      border: none;
      border-radius: 15px;
      box-shadow: 0 9px #999;
    }
    .nM_button:hover {
      background-color: #9900cc
    }
    .nM_button:active {
      background-color: #660066;
      box-shadow: 0 5px #666;
      transform: translateY(4px);
    }
    .nD_button {
      padding: 15px 25px;
      font-size: 24px;
      text-align: center;
      cursor: pointer;
      outline: none;
      color: #ffffff;
      background-color: #ff0000;
      border: none;
      border-radius: 15px;
      box-shadow: 0 9px #999;
    }
    .nD_button:hover {
      background-color: #ff0000
    }
    .nD_button:active {
      background-color: #800000;
      box-shadow: 0 5px #666;
      transform: translateY(4px);
    }
    .pD_button {
      padding: 15px 25px;
      font-size: 24px;
      text-align: center;
      cursor: pointer;
      outline: none;
      color: #ffffff;
      background-color: #33cc33;
      border: none;
      border-radius: 15px;
      box-shadow: 0 9px #999;
    }
    .pD_button:hover {
      background-color: #33cc33
    }
    .pD_button:active {
      background-color: #009900;
      box-shadow: 0 5px #666;
      transform: translateY(4px);
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body onkeydown="GetKey()">

  <div class=" month ">
    <ul>
      <li class="prev ">
        <button class="pM_button ">Prev Month</button>
      </li>
      <li class="prevDay ">
        <button class="pD_button ">Prev Day</button>
      </li>
      <li class="next ">
        <button class="nM_button ">Next Month</button>
      </li>"
      <li class="nextDay ">
        <button class="nD_button ">Next Day</button>
      </li>
      <li style="text-align:center ">
        August
        <br>
        <span style="font-size:18px ">2016</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <ul class="weekdays ">
    <li>Mo</li>
    <li>Tu</li>
    <li>We</li>
    <li>Th</li>
    <li>Fr</li>
    <li>Sa</li>
    <li>Su</li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="days ">
    <li><span class="active ">1</span>
    </li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>10</li>
    <li>11</li>
    <li>12</li>
    <li>13</li>
    <li>14</li>
    <li>15</li>
    <li>16</li>
    <li>17</li>
    <li>18</li>
    <li>19</li>
    <li>20</li>
    <li>21</li>
    <li>22</li>
    <li>23</li>
    <li>24</li>
    <li>25</li>
    <li>26</li>
    <li>27</li>
    <li>28</li>
    <li>29</li>
    <li>30</li>
    <li>31</li>
  </ul>

  <script type="text/javascript ">
    function GetKey(e) {
      var code;
      if (!e) var e = window.event;
      if (e.keyCode) code = e.keyCode;
      else if (e.which) code = e.which;
      //var character = String.fromCharCode(code);
      setTimeout('ShowTree(' + code + ');', 100);
    }

    function nextDay() {

    }

    function ShowTree(character, k) {


      //Main Menu Key
      if (character == 106) {
        cWindow.close();
      }

      //Close Key
      if (character == 111) {
        alert(" Key: / ");
        responsiveVoice.speak("Close ", "UK English Male ");
      }

      //PageUP Key, next month
      if (character == 98) {
        alert(" Key: 2 ");
        responsiveVoice.speak("Page Up ", "UK English Male ");
      }
      //PageDOWN key, previous month
      if (character == 99) {
        alert(" Key: 3 ");
        responsiveVoice.speak("Page Down ", "UK English Male ");
      }

      //Previous Key, Previous Day
      if (character == 65) { //keypad key 101
        responsiveVoice.speak("Previous ", "UK English Male ");

        //alert(" Key: 5 ");
      }

      //Next Key, Next Day
      if (character == 68) { //keypad key 102
        responsiveVoice.speak("Next ", "UK English Male ");
        $(".pD_button ").click(.days.active++);
        //alert(" Key: 6 ");
      }

      //Select Key
      if (character == 83) { //keypad key 104
        responsiveVoice.speak("Select ", "UK English Male ");

      }

      //alert(" Key: 8 ");
    }
  </script>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: To clerify my problem, I would like the button 6 on the number pad (character 102 or 68 if I don't have the keypad) to click the next button placed in the calendar header and make the next date active. Same applies with previous button except with character 65 or 101 and make the previous date active.

The solutions posted by Rimon and 030 did not work for my application - but I appreciate your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily add the `active` class to any DOM element by using `addClass("class")` and remove the class with `removeClass("class")`, provided you're using jQuery.

So if you wish to mark the `pD_button` as active, you can do it like this with jQuery

```
$(".pD_button").addClass("active");
```

If you wish to accomplish this with vanilla JavaScript you would have to write your own functions that add and remove a class.
You could do that with

classList https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

or

className https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className.

This approach is better than using the `:active` pseudo-class in CSS.
The :active pseudo-class is triggered when the mouse is being clicked, but only while the mouse button is held down. That means after you release the mouse click, `:active` is turned off. By using the approach mentioned above you just add another class when an `onclick` event happens to get the desired behavior.

```
var prevButton = $(".pD_button");
prevButton.on("click", function() {
  if (!prevButton.hasClass("active")) {
    prevButton.addClass("active");
  } else /*if (prevButton.hasClass("active"))*/ {
    prevButton.removeClass("active");
  }
});
```

You can check it out here: https://jsfiddle.net/cqm26q1n/.

It is important that the `.active` in your CSS comes after the `.pD_button` class, so that it overwrites its CSS when the `active` class get's attached to it.

EDIT:
Use the approach I suggested combined with jQuery `.keydown(handler)`:

```
var prevButton = $(".pD_button");
prevButton.on("keydown", function(e) {
  if (e.which === 102 || e.which === 68) {
    if (!prevButton.hasClass("active")) {
     prevButton.addClass("active");
    } else /*if (prevButton.hasClass("active"))*/ {
      prevButton.removeClass("active");
    }
  }
});
```

Check the documentation of keydown [here](https://api.jquery.com/keydown/).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are jQuery ( noticing presence of `$` sign and `.click` event), There are couple of errors in this section you wrote.

```
  //Next Key, Next Day
  if (character == 68) { //keypad key 102
    responsiveVoice.speak("Next ", "UK English Male ");
    $(".pD_button ").click(.days.active++);
    //alert(" Key: 6 ");
  }
```

More specifically in this like `$(".pD_button ").click(.days.active++);`

General jQuery event works like, `$("SELECTOR").EVENT(CALLBACK_FUNCTION);`

So, in your case, to go to next date, the code should be like

```
  //Next Key, Next Day
  if (character == 68) { //keypad key 102
    responsiveVoice.speak("Next ", "UK English Male ");


    $(".pD_button ").click(function(e){
        $('ul.days').find("li.active").removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
        e.preventDefault();
    });


  //alert(" Key: 6 ");
 }
```

Similarly, to go make previous date active, you just need to use `.after()` method instead of `.next()` at this line `$('ul.days').find("li.active").removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');`

To know more about jQuery [`.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) methods, check the links
https://api.jquery.com/click/ to know about `.click` event